# JavaScript: detect when CSS3 animation ended

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have simple form with ajax and I need when all thing with forms is done like in **req.done** JavaScript will wait for CSS3 animation and show **#vyhra** after CSS3 animation ended.

I tried it in the bottom in code but it not working.

```
(function($) {

var form = $('#email-form');

form.on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var req = $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: form.serialize()
    });

    req.done(function(data) {
        console.log( data );
        $('.koleso').toggleClass('koleso-active');
        form.hide();

        if($('.koleso-active').addEventListener("animationend", listener, false)) {
            $('#vyhra').show();
        }

    });

});
```

}(jQuery));

Comment: Did you try applying a `setInterval` event with the same (or maybe right after) amount of time from the animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers often fire different events for different actions.

So you'll need to listen on all of them, see the following:

So if `.koleso-active` initiates a CSS transition, you can watch the document for a transition end, like so:

```
$(document).on("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(event) {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/2fgnmxr8/1/

So yours should look something like this:

```
$(document).on("webkitTransitionEnd otransitionend oTransitionEnd msTransitionEnd transitionend", function(event) {
    $('#vyhra').show();
}
```

You may want to consider preventing it from being fired more than once, although `.show()` cannot be applied more than once (so in this case, wouldn't matter).